# Using Lists inside recipient-variables when using Batch-send via Mailgun

Tags: mailgun

I have following use case:

Batch-send invoice via Mailgun

Basically I need to combine these features:
- recipient-variables so that every receiver gets personalized email
- each recipient-variables contains list of ordered items
- each item have properties like: Name, Price, Amount, etc

I know how to use simple variables like

```
 Dear <%recipient.FirstName%>, today is <%recipient.Date%>
```

But in this case the template is more complicated, something like this (pseudo-code)

```
 Dear <%recipient.FirstName%>, these are the ordered items:
 <%each recipient.Ordered
  <%item.Name%> ...... <%item.Amount%>, <%item.Price%>
 each%>
```

It is even possible with MailGun?

Or do I have to compose the emails myself, and then just pass it to MailGun one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to compose the emails yourself, and then just pass it to MailGun one by one.

Answer (score -1):

Since you're passing a JSON object to the list when you create it, I suppose you could Have a structure such as recipient.Sales.Item1, recipient.Sales.Item2...

I'd probably try that one first.. Seems simpler, but then again, simple never is..